# Thunderbird and GMAIL Connection Error

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, mail, gmail

In morning Thunderbird was working fine and in evening it started displaying annoying message that it can't connect to my gmail account. Although Im able to access my account through web interface but can access it using Mail Client.

[image: Thunderbird]

Any suggestions

Comment: I had this issue too. I don't know how I resolved it but it's certainly an annoying issue.

Comment: hi, seeing at the screen output, I think this has nothing to do with Thunderbird. It should be a google imap fault.

Comment: @JXPheonix  No doubt its annoying , Now i have to use Web interface and found it difficult as im not used to web interface. I booted in windows 7 to check whether its isolated issue but found out that it this message is also appearing in Windows. And have no idea how to solve this one.

Comment: @bob Do u know how to solve this issue. All settings are default.

Comment: I can't post it here so I put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is posted in [gmail known issues](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs). I am sorry, it is a problem of gmail.

if you expand pop, imap & sync, then you have the following and you can report the issue (I have also done it).

'imap.gmail.com is not responding' error when retrieving mail via IMAP, mobile device, or tablet

We are aware of an issue where users are receiving an error that '"imap.gmail.com" is not responding' when using IMAP on their computers, mobile devices, or tablets. We are currently working on resolving this issue.
In the meantime, you can sign in to Gmail through a web browser. For Android and iOS users, you can also download the Gmail application in the interim.

Comment: Lets hope that they solve it soon. But still dont get it y this problem occurred in first place.Because I have changed anything

Comment: I believe that Google has solved this problem because now im able to connect to GMAIL atleast for now.

Comment: good to hear it is solved